# FFMPEG convert video into a timelapse on synology nas

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, synology

I'm trying to timelapse video from my nas synology  (surveillance station on dsm 6.1.5) with the following command:

```
sudo ffmpeg -i "20180222-080550-1519283150.mp4" -r 15 \
            -filter:v "setpts=0.001*PTS" -an test.mp4
```

but I get this error:

> Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect 
>         parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

What could be the issue?

Output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.7.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG 1.20.0) 20150311 (prerelease)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --incdir='${prefix}/include/ffmpeg' --arch=i686 --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu- --enable-cross-compile --enable-optimizations --enable-pic --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac --enable-encoders --enable-pthreads --disable-bzlib --disable-protocol=rtp --disable-muxer=image2 --disable-muxer=image2pipe --disable-swscale-alpha --disable-ffserver --disable-ffplay --disable-devices --disable-bzlib --disable-altivec --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --disable-vaapi --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=ac3 --disable-decoder=ac3_fixed --disable-encoder=zmbv --disable-encoder=dca --disable-encoder=ac3 --disable-encoder=ac3_fixed --disable-encoder=eac3 --disable-decoder=dca --disable-decoder=eac3 --disable-decoder=truehd --cc=/usr/local/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ccache-gcc --enable-yasm --enable-libx264 --enable-encoder=libx264
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/volume2/surveillance/cam1/20180222AM/cam1-20180222-080550-1519283150.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41avc1
    creation_time   : 2018-02-22 07:05:50
  Duration: 00:29:59.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 266 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 180 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 1001 tbn, 2002 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-02-22 07:05:50
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_alaw (alaw / 0x77616C61), 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-02-22 07:05:50
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'test.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41avc1
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, 15 fps (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-02-22 07:05:50
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
```

Comment: First step is to try a recent version. Either compile or try a build from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ Provide a link to a short input file so we can attempt to duplicate this issue.